# NSDictionary sets values for NSMutableDictionary

Tags: xcode, functional-programming, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to make an rpg style game. I would like to know if and how to make an NSDictionary set the value for a mutable dictionary. The characters in my game will learn moves at different levels and the user can decide which move to use. If more info is needed let me now.

Here's an example

the NSDictionary pulls from a plist of attacks.
the attacks have names and power values.
the mutable array will set its attacks to the attacks in the NSDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for NSDictionary's `- (NSArray *)objectsForKeys:(NSArray *)keys notFoundMarker:(id)anObject`
Which

> Returns the set of objects from the dictionary that corresponds to the specified keys as an NSArray.
>
> **Parameters keys** An NSArray containing the keys for which to return corresponding values.
>
> **anObject** The marker object to place in the corresponding element of the returned
>   array if an object isn’t found in the dictionary to correspond to a given key.
>
> **Discussion** The objects in the returned array and the keys array have a one-for-one correspondence, so that the nth object in the returned array corresponds to the nth key in keys.

For example, you could run `[dict objectsForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:str1, str2, nil] notFountMarker:[NSNull null]];` which will return the objects for the keys stored in str1, and str2.  If the keys aren't found, the place holder will be an NSNull object.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after a mutable copy of a dictionary . . .

```
NSDictionary *atacks = /* Your dictionary of attacks */
NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attacks];
```

Comment: I guess i should have been more specific. Lets say i want the mutable dictionary to select four rows from the ns dictionary